# Copy Data into Spreadsheet Last Active Column but in Specific Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import the data on a daily basis in the columns. However, top Rows of spreadsheet are filled with formulas till month end dates and I need to copy the data into columns after x number of rows.
When using getLastColumn, data is being pasted into last column which is last date of sheet. I'm unable to get the correct result. I'm using the below code for now -

```
function Import() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABC');
var sheet = source.getSheetByName('Export');
var copy1 = sheet.getRange(1,2,5000,1).getValues();

var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XYZ');
var final_destination = destination.getSheetByName('Import')


var paste1 = final_destination.getRange(7,final_destination.getLastColumn(),5000,1).setValues(copy1);

}
```

Below is the link of sample spreadsheet for reference -
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1apoZkPMpggqsMJd78uZIP5YlJHyCn0PTfwvZQUgsobk/edit?usp=sharing

I want to copy data from row 7 on daily basis. On next day, data will be pasted in column L, next day in column M and so on.

Kindly help with the same. Thanks.

Comment: To get a better understanding of your question I think it would be better to add a sample desired result, and the actual result of your current script.

Comment: `getLastColumn()` is going to give you the last column that has any content in it, *including* the header row. If you already have a header row for all the dates, then the last column will be last column with a header. If you need to find the first column with no data in it but with a header already, you'll have to write some conditional logic to check for empty columns. I'd need to see a sample of your current result to give more specific guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution by below code. Thanks to all for suggestions.

```
function Import() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABC');
var sheet = source.getSheetByName('Export');
var copy1 = sheet.getRange(2,2,5000,1).getValues();

var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XYZ');
var final_destination = destination.getSheetByName('Total Land Daily Actual')
var lastRow = final_destination.getRange(14,1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();

var paste1 = final_destination.getRange(14,lastRow+1,5000,1).setValues(copy1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Import() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABC');
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName('Export');
  var copy1 = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow() , 1).getValues();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XYZ');
  var final_destination = destination.getSheetByName('Import')
  var paste1 = final_destination.getRange(7, final_destination.getLastColumn(), copy1.length, 1).setValues(copy1);
}
```